# Why aren't my distribution certificates showing in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, distribution, ios-provisioning

Recently my distribution certificates have disappeared from Xcode. When I tried to add more (by double clicking on the downloaded .mobileprovision file and then Xcode opens and supposedly installs it), Xcode just ignores the files and they are not associated with my devices.

Why could this be? All the developer certificates are showing perfectly fine but no distribution ones and whatever I do - I can't install any or "un-hide" them!

Comment: Please upload the image using Stack Overflow's image hosting -- click the little photo icon above the editing field -- rather than making us download the image in order to view it.

Comment: no, I can't as I have too little reputation...

Comment: Requiring others to download files in order to address your question isn't acceptable here. If you upload it to a site like imgur, another member can edit your post to include the image inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probable thing is, you lost your private/public key pair on your Mac.
This key pairs are generated when you create CSR.

Check if you have those key pairs. if not install again (if you have back up).
If you do not have back up, create new CSR and then again generate certificate and repeat all to create new mobileprovision.

Comment: I don't quite understand what I need to install again? Could you post a link to a tutorial of where I can install that certificate from scratch?

Comment: Just login to your ios developer center > iOS provisioning Portal > provisioning > How to

Comment: I did that but couldn't find anything on how to create a CSR. What is the CSR for exactly? Could you provide an external tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: Any more ideas? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: CSR is certificate Signing Request. You should get a good document on the location i provided.

Answer (score 0):

check your certificates keys and Expiration dates also